# Windows 7, keyboard input not updating in login screen

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, localization

I recently changed the keyboard of one of my computers from a "French (Belgium)" keyboard to a "French (France)" keyboard, and as it usually causes window to do automatic switching when multiple inputs are installed, I uninstalled "French (Belgium)".

Windows session has the right input, but for some reason the input at login screen is still "French (Belgium)", this is a bit confusing when typing keyboard and I would like to correct it. How?

(I actually found that, in Windows 7, there is a localization menu at the top left of the login screen, but that one doesn't offer "French (France)", only "French (Belgium)" and English.)

Screenshot of install keyboards:

[image]

Content of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\i8042prt\Parameters as requested in comments:

[image]

I could be a TeamView issue ? according to [Windows 7 keyboard stuck on French](https://superuser.com/questions/1133488/windows-7-keyboard-stuck-on-french)

though that question isn't mentionned that its problem is only specific to login screen...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Control Panel --> Region and Language --> Keyboards and Languages --> Change Keyboards --> General tab?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: First, move the French keyboard on top of the English one. If still ng, take a look in registry key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\i8042prt\Parameters] or add to your question. (I've only used this for Japanese keyboard setting though.)

Comment: Are you sure? From what I read, i8042prt is for PS/2 keyboard, I used USB (corded) keyboard.

Comment: I just added it in question.

Comment: It must be; my keyboard is USB.

Comment: Maybe this answer could be a solution? [Windows login screen in a different keyboard 'language' than windows](https://superuser.com/a/377690/328343)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows login screen in a different keyboard 'language' than windows](https://superuser.com/questions/377569/windows-login-screen-in-a-different-keyboard-language-than-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows login screen in a different keyboard 'language' than windows](https://superuser.com/questions/377569/windows-login-screen-in-a-different-keyboard-language-than-windows)